Parsing string to dictionary
I'm working on a communications project with a radio that transmits a formatted string message, similar to:
message_string = 'Transmission\n variables \n  0.01 First variable\n  0.02 Second variable\n  0.03 Third variable \n More variables\n  0.03 Next variable\n  0.04 Another variable'

When printed, this looks like
print(message_string)
Transmission
 variables
  0.01 First variable
  0.02 Second variable
  0.03 Third variable
 More variables
  0.03 Next variable
  0.04 Another variable

This looks nice to humans, but is tricky for the computer - especially since I am trying to convert this to a python dictionary. In my actual system there are quite a few of these variables, and the code needs to systematically process all of them into a dictionary.
I think it might include something like
message_string = message_string.replace('\n','{')

but deciding which direction of brackets to use in different cases, and where to put the colons for the dictionary, is confusing me. I want an output similar to
message_dict = {
    'variables': {
       'First variable': 0.01,
       'Second variable': 0.02,
        'Third variable': 0.03},
    'More variables': {
       'Next variable': 0.03,
       'Another variable': 0.04,
    } 
}

where an error would not be thrown if one of the variables was missing from the transmission (since that sometimes happens).How do I convert this string into a dictionary?

"I want an output similar to": so you don't want to actually create the dict, but print the code for it?

@trincot no, I do actually want to create the dictionary - I just said 'similar to' because I renamed my variables before posting.

OK. Another thing: there are just as many spaces before variables as before 0.01 First variable. Either the first code line is wrong, or the second print out is wrong.

Thank you for pointing that out, I removed the extra space in the first code line.

Assuming that the indents increase with one space at a time, you could use this stack-based solution:
def to_dict(s):
    result = {}
    stack = [result]
    for line in s.splitlines():
        stripped = line.lstrip()
        indent = len(line) - len(stripped) + 1
        if indent >= len(stack):
            stack.append(None)
        if stripped[0].isdigit():
            value, key = stripped.split(" ", 1)
            stack[indent-1][key] = float(value)
        else:
            stack[indent-1][stripped] = stack[indent] = {}
    
    return result

Call it like this:
message_string = 'Transmission\n variables \n  0.01 First variable\n  0.02 Second variable\n  0.03 Third variable \n More variables\n  0.03 Next variable\n  0.04 Another variable'
d = to_dict(message_string)

For this example d will be:
{
    'Transmission': {
        'variables ': {
            'First variable': 0.01, 
            'Second variable': 0.02, 
            'Third variable ': 0.03
        }, 
        'More variables': {
            'Next variable': 0.03, 
            'Another variable': 0.04
        }
    }
}

Compared to what you wrote, this has the extra level of Transmission, but as this really is part of the input, I kept it like that.
